# New menu in context menu of totalcommander is disappear

Tags: total-commander

I am using totalcommander as main file manager tool. 
As you know, it is possible to show context menu by pressing and holding right mouse button. 
In this context menu, new menu includes normally new folder and new files supporting various file format such as *.txt, *.docx, etc. 
BTW today all new files context menus were disappeard so that I cannot use this functionality now.

How can I restore these new context menus?

Answer (score 0):

The new menu entry in the context menu appears only if you click out of any file/folder. So problable you cannot see it because your window is full (scroll bar appears on the side). There are two solutions:

1. Resize the window in order to be able to right-click out of any files/folders
2. Right click on the path